# Sql - Get the closest date for each category

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, range

I am trying to write a T-SQL query in Sql server 2008. I have a table and I am trying to find the records in each category for the closest date to today.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Spreads](
    [SpreadId] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [TeamName] [NVARCHAR](50),
    [BetAmt] [decimal](8, 2) NULL,
    [BetDate] [date] NULL)
GO



INSERT INTO dbo.SPREADS(TeamName,SpreadId, BetAmt, BetDate) VALUES('EAGLES',5260024,171,'2013-07-03');
INSERT INTO dbo.SPREADS(TeamName,SpreadId, BetAmt, BetDate) VALUES('EAGLES',5822695,106.5,'2013-08-03');
INSERT INTO dbo.SPREADS(TeamName,SpreadId, BetAmt, BetDate) VALUES('EAGLES',6527717,142,'2013-09-03');
INSERT INTO dbo.SPREADS(TeamName,SpreadId, BetAmt, BetDate) VALUES('EAGLES',7184393,177.5,'2013-10-03');
INSERT INTO dbo.SPREADS(TeamName,SpreadId, BetAmt, BetDate) VALUES('EAGLES',7844000,213,'2013-11-03');
INSERT INTO dbo.SPREADS(TeamName,SpreadId, BetAmt, BetDate) VALUES('EAGLES',8366731,248.5,'2013-12-03');
INSERT INTO dbo.SPREADS(TeamName,SpreadId, BetAmt, BetDate) VALUES('EAGLES',8743888,284,'2014-01-03');
INSERT INTO dbo.SPREADS(TeamName,SpreadId, BetAmt, BetDate) VALUES('EAGLES',9056722,319.5,'2014-02-03');
INSERT INTO dbo.SPREADS(TeamName,SpreadId, BetAmt, BetDate) VALUES('EAGLES',9401025,355,'2014-10-03');
INSERT INTO dbo.SPREADS(TeamName,SpreadId, BetAmt, BetDate) VALUES('EAGLES',9795365,390.5,'2014-11-03');
INSERT INTO dbo.SPREADS(TeamName,SpreadId, BetAmt, BetDate) VALUES('EAGLES',10190748,426,'2014-12-13');
INSERT INTO dbo.SPREADS(TeamName,SpreadId, BetAmt, BetDate) VALUES('COWBOYS',10608591,461.5,'2014-06-03');
INSERT INTO dbo.SPREADS(TeamName,SpreadId, BetAmt, BetDate) VALUES('COWBOYS',10979252,497,'2014-07-03');
INSERT INTO dbo.SPREADS(TeamName,SpreadId, BetAmt, BetDate) VALUES('COWBOYS',11375005,532.5,'2014-08-03');
INSERT INTO dbo.SPREADS(TeamName,SpreadId, BetAmt, BetDate) VALUES('COWBOYS',11821325,568,'2014-09-03');
INSERT INTO dbo.SPREADS(TeamName,SpreadId, BetAmt, BetDate) VALUES('COWBOYS',12222217,603.5,'2014-10-03');
INSERT INTO dbo.SPREADS(TeamName,SpreadId, BetAmt, BetDate) VALUES('COWBOYS',12799249,639,'2014-11-03');
INSERT INTO dbo.SPREADS(TeamName,SpreadId, BetAmt, BetDate) VALUES('COWBOYS',13164980,674.5,'2014-12-03');

GO
```

If there had been no categories, I would have written the following query:

```
Declare @today DATETIME = GETDATE();  
SELECT TOP 1 DATEDIFF(D, betdate, @today), betdate, spreadid, TeamName, betamt from Spreads
ORDER BY 1 asc
```

This returns me just 1 record, but what I am looking for is two records. For the above data, I want my query to return the records with a spreadId of 10190748 and 13164980.

Comment: What do you mean by "closest date to today" and how its related to two records you mentioned?

Comment: For TeamName=Eagles, the closest date to today is 13-Dec-2014. For Teamname=Cowboys, the closest date to today is 03-Dec-2014.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
with RecentDate as (select SpreadID
                          ,TeamName
                          ,BetAmt
                          ,BetDate
                          ,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by TeamName order by betdate desc) row_n
                    from dbo.Spreads)
Select SpreadID
      ,TeamName
      ,BetAmt
      ,BetDate
from RecentDate
where row_n = 1
```